# Convert different timezones to UTC Date

Tags: sql-server, timezone

I have a table that has date time column and timezone column in a SQL Server table. I am now trying to convert the date time from different time zones to UTC date and load the data into a new table and remove the timezone column.

For example:

```
Date time.              TIMEZONE
1/1/2020 10:34 AM       EST
1/2/2020 08:26 AM.      CST
```

New table:

```
Date time 
1/1/2020 6:34 pm
1/2/2020 4:26 pm
```

Comment: Why have you also tagged MySQL?

Comment: Be careful with time zone abbreviations.  If your data is limited to the US, you can infer `CST` means "Central Standard Time".  But if not, then you'd have to have some other way to disambiguate it from "Cuba Standard Time" and "China Standard Time", all of which have the abbreviation "CST".

Answer (score 1):

Your data is almost in a form that it can be used as is.

```
create table #d (
    dt datetime not null,
    tz char(3) not null
);

insert into #d (dt, tz)
values 
    ('1/1/2020 10:34 AM', 'EST'),
    ('1/2/2020 08:26 AM', 'CST');

create table #tz (
    tz char(3), 
    long_tz sysname not null
)

insert into #tz (tz, long_tz)
values 
    ('EST', 'Eastern Standard Time'),
    ('CST', 'Central Standard Time');

select #d.*, #d.dt at time zone #tz.long_tz at time zone 'UTC'
from #d
join #tz
    on #d.tz = #tz.tz;
```

To elaborate on what's going on here, I'm using the `at time zone` clause twice - once to tell the database what time zone the data is already recorded in and then the second to take that and convert it to UTC.

You can find the list of supported time zones in [sys.time_zone_info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-time-zone-info-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).